# Wrong value for captured value when calling boost resolve::async_resolve

Tags: c++11, lambda, boost-asio

I can't understand the behaviour of the code below.
When defining the symbol `BUG`, the third print of the variable `this` is wrong.

I think there is something in the method `resolver::async_resolve` that breaks the code. I'd like to understand what :-)

Thanks

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename F>
#ifdef BUG
void Connect( boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver& resolver, F Connected )
#else
void Connect( boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver& resolver, const F& Connected )
#endif
{
    resolver.async_resolve(
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{ "localhost", "8088" },
        [&Connected]( const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator i )
        {
            Connected();
        }
    );
}

struct Test
{
    void Start()
    {
        cout << "this1 " << hex << this << dec << endl;
        auto handler = [this]()
        {
            cout << "this2 " << hex << this << dec << endl;
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver{ ios };
            Connect( resolver, [this]()
                {
                    cout << "this3 " << hex << this << dec << std::endl;
                }
            );
        };
        handler();
        ios.run();
    }

    boost::asio::io_service ios;
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is not due to passing to `Connect` by value vs by const reference, it's undefined behaviour due to calling a dangling reference to a lambda.

This is because you're capturing `Connnected` by reference in the lambda passed to `async_resolve`.

```
resolver.async_resolve(
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{ "localhost", "8088" },
    [&Connected]( const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator i )
    {
        Connected(); // Connected is captured by reference
    }
);
```

By the time `Connected()` is called, it's been popped off the stack and destroyed.

```
void Start()
{
    cout << "this1 " << hex << this << dec << endl;
    auto handler = [this]()
    {
        cout << "this2 " << hex << this << dec << endl;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver{ ios };
        Connect( resolver, [this]()
            {
                cout << "this3 " << hex << this << dec << std::endl;
            }
        );
    };
    handler(); // after this function returns Connected will be destructed
    ios.run(); // the thread is blocked in ios.run until the resolve returns
}
```

- The call to `handler()` creates the "`Connected`" lambda on the stack and passes it to `Connect`, which in turn creates a lambda **which captures `Connected` by reference**, and starts an asynchronous operation.
- `handler()` then returns, popping "`Connected`" off the stack, destructing it.
- `ios.run()` prevents `Test::Start()` from returning as it waits for `async_resolve` to return.
- `async_resolve` completes, and calls its lambda, which in return calls `Connected()`, which has been destroyed.

You can solve this by **capturing `Connected` by-value**

```
void Connect( boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver& resolver, F Connected )
{
    resolver.async_resolve(
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{ "localhost", "8088" },
        [Connected]( const boost::system::error_code& ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator i )
        {
            Connected();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clear. It's a kind of bug tricky to spot (IMHO). I must remember that a lambda is just another object stack allocated, so I should be careful passing it by reference...  Anyone can suggest any guideline to avoid this kind of problems in the first place?